# Using Demoivre's Theorem prove that $ {\cos5 \theta} = 16{\cos^5 \theta} - 20{\cos^3 \theta} + 5{\cos \theta} $ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, trigonometric-series

$ {\cos5 \theta} = 16{\cos^5 \theta} - 20{\cos^3 \theta} + 5{\cos \theta} $ .

**Demoivre's Theorem**

$$ \{\cos \theta + i \sin \theta \}^n = \cos n\theta + i\sin n\theta $$

Where n is an integer .

I tried

$$ \{\cos \theta + i \sin \theta \}^5 - i\sin 5\theta = \cos 5\theta $$

But then I cant eliminate sines .

Comment: As @G-man has answered you need to expand the LHS of your DeMoivre's identity. $$ \{ cos\theta+\iota sin\theta \}^5$$, perhaps by rewrtiing as $$ \{ \{ cos\theta+\iota sin\theta \}^2 \}^2 \{ cos\theta+\iota sin\theta\} $$.

Comment: It would be easier to just apply the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to eliminate anything. Just equate the real parts on the LHS and the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $(\cos \theta \pm i\sin \theta)^5=\cos 5\theta \pm i\sin 5\theta$. Add them and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\cos5\theta=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^5-i\sin 5\theta$$
$$=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^2(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^3-i\sin 5\theta$$
$$=(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta+2i\sin\theta\cos\theta)(\cos^3\theta-3\sin^2\theta\cos\theta-i\sin^3\theta+3i\sin\theta\cos^2\theta)-i\sin 5\theta$$
comparing the real parts on both the sides, one should get 
$$\cos5\theta=(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)(\cos^3\theta-3\sin^2\theta\cos\theta)$$$$+2\sin\theta\cos\theta(\sin^3\theta-3\sin\theta\cos^2\theta)$$

$$\cos5\theta=(2\cos^2\theta-1)(4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta)+2\cos\theta(1-\cos^2\theta)(1-4\cos^2\theta)$$
$$\cos5\theta=16\cos^5\theta-20\cos^3\theta+5\cos\theta$$